# How to install a VSCode extension locally?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VSCode installed (1.30.2v) in my Linux from IT. I want to install an extension. Since I can't modify the area of the VSCode, and therefore I can't install the externation, I'm trying to figure out how to install it locally and make the VSCode use it. When I click on the `install` button of an externatino in the marketplace I get:

```
fail to install 'extension'
```

Then I clicked on the `Install Manually` button and downloaded the `<extension>.vslx` file. After that I click on the "Install from VSIX" button and chose the `<extension>.vslx` file. But it didn't do anything - didn't show any error and didn't install the extension. I think it still tries to install it in the `VSCode` area. How can I install it locally?

Comment: Sounds like your IT gives you a customized version of VSCode, so you shouldn't expect an answer from outsiders but the IT guys of your organization.

Comment: @LexLi But they just installed it. I thought there would be some env or settings that I could modify to install exertions locally.

Comment: just copy your dev extension directory to the VSC User entension directory: `~/.vscode/extensions`, or package to a `.vsix` and use extension bar to install from VSIX file